# Multicore Solving of Sparse Matrices in R

Tags: r, multithreading, multiprocessing, sparse-matrix, blas

For an analysis I need to solve a large sparse system in the form *Ax=b*. *A* has the dimension of *3Mx3M* and is positive definite.

For now, I use the 'Matrix' package which provides support for sparse matrices and a working solver. I manage to solve my problem in about 40 seconds. However, currently 31 of the 32 cores of my server are laughing at me, because I can only use a single core for my calculations.

I tried making a foreach routine, but this is very RAM/overhead intensive. I would rather use something like a BLAS/LAPACK solver with integrated multicore support. Microsoft R Open seemed promising, but it only supports BLAS/LAPACK for dense matrices. I tried Googling extensively to no avail.

Is an accessible multicore solver available for solving sparse matrices in R?

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Not R, but take a look at the PETSc library. It rely on MPI for parallelism and there is a large number of [solvers and preconditionners](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/linearsolvertable.html) available for sparce positive definite matrices (aij/baij). Or you may use a parallel direct solver such as MUMPS. See [there](http://www.nersc.gov/users/software/programming-libraries/math-libraries/petsc/c-example-mumps/) for an example. But there is a need to write an interface to call the c function from R.

Comment: Also note, that in many cases linear algebra on sparse matrices is memory bound, not CPU bound...

Comment: You are right in general, Dmitriy Selivanov. However, my machine has 250+GB RAM, so I think memory is not the bottleneck in my calculations. My sparse matrices are in the order of 800MB each.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to recompile your R with a BLAS library, you can take a look at something like this: [Using Intel MKL with R](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r)

Comment: BLAS works with dense matrices! For most POSIX systems recompilation is also not necessary in most cases.

Comment: This indeed seems like the way to go! I will try to report my findings here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I @WvWestering did u find any solution with BLAS library ?

Comment: @ChristopheD. I did give it a try and did not succeed yet. However, I am inexperienced with compiling my own R libraries and I still think this is the way to go. Hopefully I will get it working in the future.